# What is the CDI equivalent of EJB's SessionSynchronization#afterCompletion method?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, jta

I've read CDI 2.0 specification (JSR 365) and found out the existence of the `@Observes(during=AFTER_SUCCESS)` annotation, but it actually requires a custom event to be defined in order to work.

This is what i've got:

```
//simple """transactional""" file system manager using command pattern  

@Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
@TransactionScoped
@Stateful
public class TransactionalFileSystemManager implements SessionSynchronization {
    private final Deque<Command> commands = new ArrayDeque<>();

    public void createFile(InputStream content, Path path, String name) throws IOException {
        CreateFile command = CreateFile.execute(content, path, name);
        commands.addLast(command);
    }

    public void deleteFile(Path path) throws IOException {
        DeleteFile command = DeleteFile.execute(path);
        commands.addLast(command);
    }

    private void commit() throws IOException{
        for(Command c : commands){
            c.confirm();
        }
    }

    private void rollback() throws IOException{
        Iterator<Command> it = commands.descendingIterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Command c = it.next();
            c.undo();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterBegin() throws EJBException{

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeCompletion() throws EJBException{

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(boolean commitSucceeded) throws EJBException{
        if(commitSucceeded){
            try {
                commit();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new EJBException(e);
            }
        }
        else {
            try {
                rollback();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new EJBException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I want to adopt a CDI-only solution so I need to remove anything EJB related (including the `SessionSynchronization` interface). How can i achieve the same result using CDI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the facts: the authoritative source for this topic is the Java Transaction API (JTA) specification. Search for it online, I got [this](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jta-1_2-mrel2-spec/JTA1.2Specification.pdf).

Then the bad news: In order to truly participate in a JTA transaction, you either have to implement a connector according to the Java Connector Architecture (JCA) specification or a `XAResource` according to JTA. Never done any of them, I am afraid both are going to be hard. Nevertheless, if you search, you may find an existing implementation of a File System Connector.

Your code above will never accomplish true 2-phase commit because, if your code fails, the transaction is already committed, so the application state is inconsistent. Or, there is a small time window when the real transaction is committed but the file system change have not beed executed, again the state is inconsistent.

Some *workarounds* I can think of, none of which solves the consistency problem:

- Persist the File System commands in a database. This ensures that they are enqueued transactionally. A scheduled job wakes up and actually tries to execute the queued FS commands.
- Register a [`Synchronization`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/transaction/Synchronization.html) with the current [`Transaction`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/transaction/Transaction.html#registerSynchronization-javax.transaction.Synchronization-), fire an appropriate event from there. Your `TransactionalFileSystemManager` observes this event, no `during` attribute needed I guess.

Comment: My goal is to detect inconsistent states, not to prevent them: the ``execute()`` method is executed **during** the transaction and creates the file with a placeholder name ("new_FILENAME"), while the ``confirm()`` and ``undo()`` method simply remove the file or rename it (and if they fail i can see which files still have the placeholder name). This is really nothing too serious and i'm even fine with the small inconsistency state time window. For more serious use cases i'd certainly use something else (like txfs?), but for now your ``Synchronization`` solution did the trick